# why tornado TCPClient.connect return a Future object?

Tags: python, tornado

In the official docs that says:

> `class tornado.tcpclient.TCPClient(resolver=None, io_loop=None)`
>
> > `connect(host, port, af=<AddressFamily.AF_UNSPEC: 0>, ssl_options=None, max_buffer_size=None)`
>
> Asynchronously returns an **`IOStream`**

### but

```
import tornado.gen
import tornado.tcpclient
import tornado.ioloop
@tornado.gen.coroutine
def main():
    return tornado.tcpclient.TCPClient.connect('127.0.0.1', '8888')
result = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().run_sync(main)
```

I thought the result is a IOStream object.In fact, It's a Future object.

So, why isn't it a IOStream object ?

Comment: because it returns IOStream _asynchronously_.

Comment: what should i do if i want get a IOStream ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the document http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/tcpclient.html says:
Asynchronously returns an IOStream (or SSLIOStream if ssl_options is not None).

in tornado, the asynchronous methods return future object.

Comment: so it can't get the IOStream?

Comment: you can get IOStream with `yield`. And use `raise tornado.gen.Return()` to return it.  see: you need think differently when using asynchronization.

Comment: thank you so much. in tornado it seems there are lots of things i need to learn.